# Wireless communication between multiple adhoc nodes in omnet++ using inet

Tags: omnet++, inet

Yes I have viewed the wireless tutorial offered by `inet` but it has not been of any help to me. I am currently making a simple `omnet++` project that references `inet` folder to create multiple adhoc nodes with limited communication ranges.

I would like for these nodes to broadcast hello every so many seconds and when they are within range of one another to receive the hello message. I've looked into the inet adhoc projects, the ini files I have seen show the `ping` and `udp` format calls, but not how to actually use the `ping` and `udp` methods.

Where I wish to send and handle messages in my cc file. I would like to use tcp for sending messages, but I don't quite understand how to send up the tcp and send the messages within the cc file.

I don't know if in and out gates should be initialized for these nodes or on the network, or even at all since they are wireless?

I have read several places that state since I am using the radio I may use a function called `sendDirect`, but I don't know the destination node ID I need to send to when using that function.

I just started using `omnet++` a month ago, I finished the tictoc tutorial, but it was a tutorial for wired networks so it also has not been much help to me. So please help me further my knowledge and understanding of `omnet++` and `inet`! Examples of cc file code pertaining to this question would be much appreciated since there are very few examples online.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I recommend that you separate your post into multiple, asking only one, well formatted question per post.  It's much easier to help when dealing with a single issue rather than a bunch thrown together.

Comment: Sorry, for the format. My main question is how can I broadcast and listen for a message within the communication range of an adhoc node, while implementing this within my cc file?